A widower with 3 children wins a female android at a football game
A novel about a widower with three children in the future. He is given free tickets to the 49er game but the kicker is he asks a girl if she is a robot he gets to take her home. He wins and takes her home to his kids and falls in love with her They are in a car accident similar to the one which killed his wife. Then after a journalist tells his story the rush of funding from the community and also the widow of the man who killed his wife enables him to buy a replacement with her restored memory

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Was it a hardcover, paperback, or e-book?  Did the story take place in San Francisco?  How futuristic was the setting?

It was an Ebook a few years ago

@Nrf It seems you are using a different account to interact on this post. To regain access to your old account, merge your two accounts by following the procedure described in the Help Center, which will allow you to mark an answer as accepted.

This is The eGirl by Michael Dalton.

Paul Dawson lost his wife in a tragic car accident 18 months ago, leaving him alone to raise his three kids. Lonely but still bereaved, he’s been unable to find a way past his grief, and Paul’s kids—especially his teenage daughter Alisa—have resisted his efforts to begin dating again.
One afternoon at a football game, Paul wins a robot in a corporate promotion. But this robot—the new Vertex eGirl 5—is unlike anything Paul or anyone else has seen before.


Yes thank you that is the book I was looking for!!! Yay!

@Nrf - Great. Don't forget to use the "accept" button to show that it's solved.
